# How to fork a child process with electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a simple nodeJS app that has a function to scrape file metadata.  Since scraping metadata can be intensive I made the app run this as a child process using fork.

```
const metaParser = child.fork(  fe.join(__dirname, 'parse-metadata.js'), [jsonLoad]);
```

Everything worked great until I ported this to electron.  When run in main.js  the process is successfully created, but immediately exits.  I added some logging to parse-metadata.js and found out that parse-metadata.js executed successfully and ran long enough to run the first few lines of code and then exited.

How do I get electron to fork parse-metadata.js and keep it alive until the end?

I'm using electron v1.4.15 and  Node v6

Comment: did you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172308/spawn-a-child-process-in-electron

Comment: Yea I saw that.  It doesn't explain the behavior I'm seeing

Answer (score 1):

When using the detached option to start a long-running process, the process will not stay running in the background unless it is provided with a stdio configuration that is not connected to the parent.
Also it seems related to the env.

Look at this: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6868