# Is it possible to call a native process in Electron?

Tags: electron

Is it possible to call a native process in Electron?

For example, if I want to call `git` or something like that is it possible?

Example:

```
var process = new Process();
process.executable = File.ApplicationDirectory() + "/utilities/my_process_not_node_js";
process.arguments = "-html=5 -include-css=true -mobile-support=true";
process.addEventListener("standardInput", handleInput);
process.run();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spawn a child process in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172308/spawn-a-child-process-in-electron)

Comment: @DannyBuonocore I've added more details.

Comment: Probably you could use some thing like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941083/execute-and-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can you have access to the complete NodeJS builtin API.

For example if you want to execute a simple `ls -lh /usr` command, you can do:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(`stdout: ${data}`));

ls.stderr.on('data', data => console.log(`stderr: ${data}`));

ls.on('close', code => console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`));
```